# How should I add users non-interactively?

Tags: bash, useradd

I have a set of users I need to add to a new system as part of a BASH script that preps my server. How can I non-interactively add the user, create their home directory, set the group, and enter a default password?

For example, if I needed to add the following users, how would I go about that?

```
user: node
password: spoon
group: ultraMegaPermissions

user:serve
password: spoot
group: sortaNotMega

user:watcher
password: spoogle
group: notMega
```

Comment: Which operating system? On my Linux `useradd` (different than `adduser`, but form the same _shadow_ package) handles command line parameters: `useradd -p spoon -g ultraMegaPermissions -m node`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an old question, but curious, others can consider the command `newusers`.  This is present on both a RHEL5.5 system and a Ubuntu 12.04 system that I use, so I'd take a guess it will be available in the repositories for most distributions.

From `man newusers`:

> The newusers command reads a file of user name and clear-text password
>      pairs and uses this information to update a group of existing users or
>      to create new users. Each line is in the same format as the standard
>      password file (see passwd(5)) with the exceptions explained below

Comment: no, that would be easy and obviously silly =)

Answer (score 7):

Use `useradd` on Linux, at least.

Use [`crypt(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) to generate an encrypted password, and then do the following for each:

```
useradd -m -g [group] -p [crypt output] [user]
```

`-m` creates a home directory. `-g` sets the user's initial login group. `-p` sets the encrypted password, as returned by `crypt(3)` (you should note that this option may be unsuitable as the encrypted password will be visible to users listing the processes when the user is being created).

You will probably want to use other options too (at a guess, at least `-s`), read `man 8 useradd` for those.

Comment: Cheers! This worked for me very well for creating a user with a password from within a Dockerfile which used a alpine linux as its base image. Had to add an extra repository `RUN echo http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ >> /etc/apk/repositories` and then install `apk add shadow` which provides crypt.

Answer (score 0):

If you need manually input user password:

```
echo -n "Enter $MY_USER password: "
read -sa MY_PASS
echo ${MY_USER}:${MY_PASS}::::/home/${MY_USER}:${DEFAULT_SHELL} | newusers
```

And if you need it totally non-interactive, just run the last command with clear text password ($MY_PASS), which normally not a good idea

Answer (score -1):

In case newuser command do not exists on the server.

You can use take the help of passwd command.

```
 echo "new_passwd" | passwd  --stdin new_user
```

Comment: Does not work on my Ubuntu 14.04