# Best way to create a user with a password without any user interaction? (asking user for password) (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, python

I'm creating a python script that will create user accounts with an username and a password from an excile file. I'm having trouble finding a one line command that will create an user with a password though. I have tried "useradd" with the p-flag but it tells me that the password is wrong when I'm trying to login. I've also tried "adduser" but I haven't found a way yet. It seems like the user himself has to enter the password.

**What I want to do:** Create an user account with a password preferably with an one-line command.

Here is my python code at the moment that just creates the user accounts without a password:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import openpyxl
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

excel_file = os.open("Names_mod.xlsx", os.O_RDONLY)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Names_mod.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active
max_row = sheet.max_row

for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
    name = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 5)  
    password = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 6)
    addUser = "sudo useradd -m  " + name.value
    os.system(addUser)
```

Comment: Related, on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2150882. The accepted answer likely doesn't work, as stated in comments, but `chpasswd` (from the second ranked answer) may be what you are looking for. All readers: feel free to make a full answer from this.

Comment: Related: `newusers` (provided by `passwd` on Ubuntu): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21022/315749

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it yet but it looks like you need to pass in a password that has already been encrypted from `man useradd` on ubuntu (that's probably why it didn't work before):

```
       -p, --password PASSWORD
           The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.

           Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.

           You should make sure the password respects the system's password policy.
```

The crypt module exists in python 2 and 3. For python 3 you can use crypt.crypt(password)
This worked for me:

```
python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import crypt
>>> crypt.crypt("hello")
'$6$AFKk6qImS5R6bf//$Voc7MRbOX5R2R8GvmmEHxVgx/wVorKO4y2Vuufgkph798mo/SJ6ON8vKJWj1JTsRdwNyb9oiTmHiNYGiOL4Q20'
>>>
```

For python 2 you need to pass the salt as the second argument as well. Be careful about choosing different salts for different users.

So tl;dr in python3 try:

```
import crypt

...

for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
    name = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 5)  
    password = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 6)
    encrypted_password = crypt.crypt(password)
    addUser = "sudo useradd -m  " + name.value + " -p " + encrypted_password
    os.system(addUser)
```

EDIT: From the original poster this doesn't work in python2, the password is still wrong. I haven't tested the actual login in python3 either though.
For python2 this doesn't work:

```
for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
    name = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 5)  
    password = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 6)
    encrypted_password = crypt.crypt(password, name.value)
    # This doesnt work!
    addUser = "sudo useradd -m  " + name.value + " -p " + encrypted_password
    os.system(addUser)
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! This worked!

Comment: Never mind, I thought it worked but now I'm getting this error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./uppgift2.py", line 18, in <module>
    encrypted_password = crypt.crypt(password)
TypeError: crypt() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: @KarlOlsson I think you are using python2, you have to give it a salt too. Try crypt.crypt(password, name.value) (im not sure what the best salt to give it though in python2)

Comment: Oh, for some reason I thought I used python 3, my bad! Now it runs without problem but it still tells me that the password is wrong when I try and login with one of the accounts. I appreciate the help mate!

Comment: ah dang.. when i tried with python3 it looked a little better, maybe it doesn't work in python2, or there is some other mistake... Your welcome! hopefully it helped anyways!

Comment: I have read so many pages on this subject and auth kept on failing. In the end this was caused by not escaping the $'s in the hash.

My solution:


`useradd <username> --password $(echo -n "<hash>" | base64 --decode)`

Just to be clear; the hash is something like:

$6$salt$.....